# How to match the string after the character and space in Python3?

Tags: python, string, extract

I have the following string:

`'- Submission GMV / return finance027110/06 Abdul Rahman -26,00- Submission GMV / return finance02432548/08 Michael Scott -56,47- GMV success. 452630/10/21 Lehazq998890/92 +60,00'`

How can I return the values as:

```
[['- Submission PVT / return finance027110/06 Abdul Rahman','-26,00'],
 ['- Submission LTD / return finance02432548/08 Michael Scott','-56,47'],
 ['- GMV success. 452630/10/21 Lehazq998890/92', '+60,00']]
```

I'm looping into multiple input.  Hence, the count of output rows differs in each iteration.  But the split pattern remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is easy to come by using `re.findall` with two capture groups:

```py
inp = "- Submission GMV / return finance027110/06 Abdul Rahman -26,00- Submission GMV / return finance02432548/08 Michael Scott -56,47- GMV success. 452630/10/21 Lehazq998890/92 +60,00"
matches = re.findall(r'(-.*?) ([+-]\d+(?:,\d+)?)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('- Submission GMV / return finance027110/06 Abdul Rahman', '-26,00'),
 ('- Submission GMV / return finance02432548/08 Michael Scott', '-56,47'),
 ('- GMV success. 452630/10/21 Lehazq998890/92', '+60,00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this `data.split('- ')[1:]`